# Very slow look-behind

Tags: java, regex, performance, scala

I'm trying to recover two positions using java regex

The first one is given by the regex:

```
val r="""(?=(?<=[ ]|^)[^ ]{1,21474836}(?=[ ]|$)(?<=[^A-Z]|^)[A-Z]{1,21474836}(?=[^A-Z]|$))"""
```

The second one is given by the regex

```
val p="""(?<=(?<=[ ]|^)[^ ]{1,21474836}(?=[ ]|$)(?<=[^A-Z]|^)[A-Z]{1,21474836}(?=[^A-Z]|$))"""
```

Note that the two expressions are identical, except the first "=" is replaced by an "<=" in the second expression. I am [not using neste quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5011672/1287856) here.

My command to test it is the following:

```
r.findAllMatchIn("a <b/>"*100) //.... some long string of size 600...
p.findAllMatchIn("a <b/>"*100) //.... some long string of size 600...
```

The first example is almost instant during execution, whereas the second takes dozens of seconds. If I launch the same examples in a REPL, both are very fast.

Where does that come from?  How can I make the second expression faster?

**Update: Why this matters**

Note that in general, I can have expressions of the type:

```
[^ ]+[^.]+
```

and I would like to know when this regular expression can be found on the left of a given position, or when it can end.
If I have the following data with the position below it:

```
abc145A
0123456
```

I would like the end of the previous expression to match position 1,2,3,4,5 and 6. If I use non-greedy repeating jokers, then it will match 1,3 and 5. If I use greedy operators, it matches only 6. This is why I need look-behind assertions. Or you will find me a way to define operators to find the positions I am looking for.

Comment: I'm guessing the double lookbehind is causing it to loop over the same characters repeatedly - taking O(n^2) time instead of O(n) time.

Comment: Another possibility: {1,21474836} is a really, really big range, and the time taken by the lookbehind that contains it might be proportional to the size of that range.

Comment: I tried to lower the number to 2000 but it does not change anything.

Comment: What if you reduce it to 10?  (Java might be reducing it to the length of the string you're searching through automatically.)

Comment: Reducing it to 10 improves the speed by a factor 4.

Comment: Can your results include spaces anywhere?  It looks to me like those regexes could almost be replaced with a call to `String.split(" ")`.

Comment: The first Regex can be read as "matches where there is a space token followed by an uppercase word"

Comment: I can't get the given regex to match anything.  It's probably because of the `(?=[ ]|$)` and `[A-Z]` parts, which basically say that the next character must be a space, but must also be a capital letter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49423/discussion-between-brilliand-and-mikael-mayer)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using nested quantifiers, but I suspect nested lookbehinds cause a similar problem.  I suspect you don't need that outer lookahead/lookbehind at all - how about performing a single regex search using only the inner part of the regexes (common to both), and retrieving both the start position and the end position from each result?

Comment: I already tried before this approach, and it does not work in all cases. Indeed, if I use a single expression, it may match tokens which are too long and would hide another appearance of the token

Comment: You could get around that by searching for one match at a time in a loop, rather than searching for all matches with one method call.  Alternately, you could put a group in the first regex (put parenthesis around "[^ ]{1,21474836}"), and use its length to determine where the end position is.